# How can i use my if else condition using Boolean expression as True and False

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
payload=[{'id': 'Room1','pressure': {'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': ''},'temperature'{'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value': ''},'humidity'{'metadata': {}, 'type': 
'Number', 'value': '89','type': 'RoomTest'}]
attrs=['temperature','pressure','humidity']
x=(len(payload))
for i in range(x):
    for j in attrs:
    y=payload[i][j]['value']
    print(y)
       if 'Null' in y or 'None' in y:
          print('Notification Not processed because of Null or empty value')
       else:
          print('Notification successfully processed')
```

I want to use Boolean expression as True of False eg:, if i define Flag=true for condition **if 'Null' in y or 'None' in y:** it execute it and return True with  message ('Notification Not processed because of Null or empty value') otherwise go to else part of code and print ('Notification successfully processed').

Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assign the boolean expression you want to a variable:

```
b = 'Null' in y or 'None' in y
```

Then you can use the variable as a boolean:

```
if b:
    print('Notification Not processed')
else: 
    print('Notification processed')
```

Note that if you call `print(b)` it will print either `True` or `False`.

To assign, do `b = True` or `b = False` (without quotes)

Comment: Thanks @Mr.K , can u elaborate,To assign, do b = True or b = False (without quotes)

Comment: If you want to assign a bool variable with a value (e.g. `if a<b: found = True`) then you can use said syntax, without quotes. Just an additional info, because you know in python we can't (fully) designate the type of variables.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm understood your question you wanna add an flag variable which can be used for control of your if statement, in provided code from questions it's not necessary to use Boolean expression, just simplify your current logic:

```py
payload = [
    {
        'id': 'Room1',
        'pressure': {
            'metadata': {}, 
            'type': 'Number', 
            'value': ''
        },
        'temperature': {
            'metadata': {}, 
            'type': 'Number', 
            'value': ''
        },
        'humidity': {
            'metadata': {}, 
            'type': 'Number', 
            'value': '89',
            'type': 'RoomTest'
        }
    }
]

attrs=['temperature', 'pressure', 'humidity']
flag = True
for i in payload:
    for j in attrs:
        val = i[j].get('value')
        if not val and flag:
            print('Notification Not processed because of Null or empty value')
        else:
            print('Notification successfully processed')
```

Otherwise with Boolean expression its will look as something like this:

```py
payload = [
    {
        'id': 'Room1',
        'pressure': {
            'metadata': {}, 
            'type': 'Number', 
            'value': ''
        },
        'temperature': {
            'metadata': {}, 
            'type': 'Number', 
            'value': ''
        },
        'humidity': {
            'metadata': {}, 
            'type': 'Number', 
            'value': '89',
            'type': 'RoomTest'
        }
    }
]

attrs=['temperature', 'pressure', 'humidity']
flag = True
for i in payload:
    for j in attrs:
        val = i[j].get('value')
        check = True
        check &= not val
        check &= flag
        if check:
            print('Notification Not processed because of Null or empty value')
        else:
            print('Notification successfully processed')
```

In both cases you just can change value of the `flag` variable